# Windows WiFi connection rapidly fluctuating, causes most requests to fail

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns

I started having issues after I programatically changed quite a few windows 7 settings. I thought I had reversed everything, but apparently something stuck. I can connect to the network, but it switches between saying I have internet, I am connected but don't have internet, and occasionally disconnecting and reconnecting me. In the browser, page loads just hang until they fail with a "change in network connection" or DNS lookup failiure.

Initially, I thought it would just be something simple. After a few hours of fruitlessly messing with various network related settings, I started to get a little more desperate; here are some things I have tried:

- Used a system restore point from a few days ago
- Restarted router
- Reinstalled wireless card drivers
- Deleted all network profiles and added the network from scratch

Even more interestingly, I can use every other wifi network to access the internet other than this one, so my wireless card isn't fried. To top it off, it's impossible to access webpages through the browser on this network, but when I just send requests over and over again through Python, about one in ten actually succeed.

My best guess is that it has to do with this network rejecting requests with a certain number of packet errors, but I have no idea how I'd go about fixing this. Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Have you checked your dns settings? Have you tried changing your dns to google ? 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: @spuder Just changed the IPv4 to those and it looked very promising. Skype managed to connect and I loaded a webpage, but then it went back to the same old connecting and reconnecting. Are there any public DNS servers like that for IPv6?

Comment: You could also use the google ipv6 dns servers. However most internet providers still don't offer ipv6 (except though ipv6 to ipv4 tunneling) Those servers are here https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: No dice using those either. Any other possible solutions? I just don't want to have to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Can you take ipv6 out of the equation and just use ipv4?

Comment: Disabling IPv6 just leaves me with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your Windows setup seems very loused up and I don't think we can find out what's wrong without
some hands-on.

My suggestions are :

1. Try going to an earlier restore-point than the one you used.
2. Try [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).
3. Do [Repair Install to Fix Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).
   This is a soft
   re-installation of Windows, basically an in-place upgrade
   that will refresh Windows while preserving
   your user-accounts, data, programs, and system drivers.

If none of these works, you might have to bite the bullet and do a full reinstall.

Take good backups before starting and ensure you can reinstall all your installed products
(installation media and serial numbers).

Comment: I should have read the question more carefully, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a race condition try;

1. Go to your **Event Viewer** (Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer)
2. Once in the **Event Viewer**, Click on (**Windows Logs** > **System** )
3. Scroll down until you see any events pertaining to your issue.

Likely you'll see what the problem is right away. This sounds like you could have a hostname conflict; is there another computer on your network with the same name? If so, you will need to change your **Computer Name** to something different and that can be done in **System Properties**

If the event viewer is displaying something different post what the error is, and I'm sure you'll get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have probably tried this, but possibly the reason is because the ip address is set to a static value rather than being assigned automatically.

Try deleting the ip address as follows:

1. Go to wireless network properties (Right click network > Status > Properties)
2. Click on Internet Protocol Version 4 or 6.
3. Click properties.
4. Make sure that they are both set to obtain IP Address automatically.

Comment: System restore rollback should have fixed that.